# Discard changes in several files at once using GitHub for Windows

Tags: github-for-windows

Is it possible to discard changes in several files at once using GitHub for Windows?

We can do it for a specific file:

[image]

or for all files:

[image]

But I can't find the option to discard changes in several selected files at once using GitHub for Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of now, GitHub does not allow this: it is not possible to discard changes in several files at once using GitHub for Windows.